# Can't start datanode and name node.

Tags: hadoop2

all.sh,  I get this error:

> Incorrect configuration: namenode address
>   dfs.namenode.servicerpc-address or dfs.namenode.rpc-address is not
>   configured. Stopping namenodes on []

I looked at all the .xml file and I can't seem to find any problem. Please find the xml files configuration below.

hdfs-site.xml

```
<configuration>
<property>
    <name>dfs.replication</name>
    <value>1</value>
</property>
<property> 
    <name>dfs.namenode.name.dir</name> 
    <value>file:/usr/local/hadoop_tmp/hdfs/namenode</value> 
</property> 

<property> 
    <name>dfs.datanode.data.dir</name> 
    <value>file:/usr/local/hadoop_tmp/hdfs/datanode</value> 
</property> 

</configuration>
```

core-site.xml

```
<property>
    <name>fs.default.name</name>
    <value> hdfs://localhost:9000</value>
</property>

</configuration>
```

mapred-site.xml

```
<property>
    <name>mapreduce.framework.name</name>
    <value>yarn</value>
</property>

</configuration>
```

yarn-site.xml

```
<configuration>

<property>
    <name>yarn.nodemanager.aux-services</name>
    <value>mapreduce_shuffle</value>
</property>
<property>
    <name>yarn.nodemanager.aux-services.mapreduce.Shuffle.class</name>
    <value>org.apache.hadoop.mapred.ShuffleHandler</value>
</property>

</configuration>
```

Thank you.